# How to create an offline form for submitting WP posts

Tags: wordpress, forms, submission

You may have seen WP plugins that allow guests to submit posts. Those submissions proceed to the WP posts area where the admin can edit/publish them.

I want to create a form like this that I can install on my (and other people's) computers, so they can fill out the form fields for a WP post, save offline, then send to my WP site when ready.

Can anyone tell me the steps involved, and, if there is a description for what type of thing this is, please let me know to aid my search.

I am learning code at present and want to learn while building tools.

Thanks

Comment: You could be using an offline editor; something like [Windows Live Writer](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-live/essentials-other#essentials=writerother) or [MarsEdit](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/marsedit-blog-editor-for-wordpress/id402376225?mt=12) for OSX

Comment: Yes I'm familiar with those tools, but their limitation is that they don't include WP-specific functions (notable meta information and feat. image).

Answer (score 0):

Hi hope I can give you some hints with this answer.

I don't know what programming language you would like to use, but for the communication with your Wordpress blog you could use the [WP API](http://wp-api.org/) to create a post over REST API. It offers a API to create and edit your Wordpress Posts over HTTP.

Your programm just have to check if an connection is possible and then execute the API calls.

You could use an database to store all created post and then call the Create Post Task with the POST Method over HTTP for each post saved offline. 
When the creation was successful you could update your offline database, so that the post is marked as already created.